# How do I align two words so that they are exactly below each other?

Tags: google-docs

I want to write a text with literal translations exactly under each word.
How do I make sure that the translated word is perfectly aligned with its counterpart in the other language?

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Have tried using tabs or inserting the words inside a table with no borders?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to set left-tab stops at the spacing you want, and then use tab to separate the words. The left-tab stops can be adjusted and essentially allow you to customize the amount of space that the tab key takes up.

In Google Docs, you access the tab-stop menu by left-clicking on the ruler bar and selecting "Add left-tab stop" from the contextual menu. Once you've added a tab-stop, you can move it side to side to customize the spacing. You can also drag it off the ruler if you want to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Insert tabs to separate the words. The words will then be aligned.

[image]

Comment: Tabs work, but the gap is huge. Table without borders / with white borders works! Thanks!